# How to unhide apps that has been hidden in the play store?

Tags: google-play-store

On the play store, I can hide apps I previously installed/bought by clicking on the "x".

How do I reverse this process? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well pressing the install button will make they appear there again, duh.